# Reading .xls into a dataframe leads to meaningless letters and characters- looks like encoding error?

Tags: python, pandas, xls

I'm trying to parse some data from an external provider excel file into a pandas dataframe for analysis. Dataset is fully visible in Excel (153 cols x 1926 rows of string & float data), but throws out a series of meaningless text when read into the dataframe (see pic). I'm using 2.7 Python Environment in anaconda, jupyter notebook on a Macbook Air. I'm using the standard read in code with no errors

`df1 = pd.read_excel(sourcedir, header = 3, sheet_name='Sheet1')`

I've tried specifying encoding as 'utf-8' and 'ascii' without any improvement.

Any ideas for how to read this in properly?

[Here's an example of one dataframe output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J6XEx.png)
[Here's a snip of the original data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QOs0O.png)

Comment: Hi, Could you please show how the original data looks like? Thanks

Comment: Hey! Thanks I've updated the post. The dataset is too large to fully show, but I've given a sample screenshot and dimensions (153cols X 1964rows).

Comment: Hi! This is quite interesting. Unfortunately, I can't replicate it. Do all columns show up like that or only some? Maybe it's some data types used by .xls? I would try saving the .xls file as .csv (in Excel) and then read as a csv in pandas.

Comment: A workaround could be to export from excel as CSV file (file->save as -> choose CSV as file format) and then import the csv in python with `pd.read_csv("filename.csv")`. Seeing if this works or not can help to understand why the direct excel import is not working.